# Surjective $p$-adic representation implies trivial $p$-primary part.

Tags: elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve. We know that by Serre in the non-CM case, for $p\geq5$,

$$\rho_p:Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow Aut(T_p(E))$$

is surjective iff

$$ \bar{\rho}_p:Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow Aut(E[p])$$

is surjective.

How does surjectivity imply that $E(\mathbb{Q})(p)$ is trivial?

I know that the maps are injective, so surjectivity then gives bijectivity. I'm trying to understand the how the maps actually operate. Any hints on this or links to articles where this is explained will be helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry but are you saying that $Gal(\bar {\Bbb Q}/\Bbb Q)$ is isomorphic to a finite group ?

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific in that $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ is associated to $E$.

Comment: The second map is obviously not injective. Also the absolute galois group of the rationals doens't depend on any elliptic curve so you can't say it is associated to $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E(\Bbb Q)(p)$ is not trivial, then $E(\Bbb Q)$ has a nontrivial point $P$ of order $p$.
Because $P$ is rational, it is invariant under the action of $\bar{\rho_p}$.

On the other hand for any nonzero point $Q \in E[p]$ there are maps in $Aut(E[p])$ that don't fix $Q$, so $\bar{\rho_p}$ can't be surjective.

Comment: Just a trivial point, but do you mean that $P$ is of order $p^k$?

Comment: no because if there is a point $Q$ of order $p^k$ then $P = p^{k-1}Q$ is a point of order $p$.